# looping through nodes xslt python

Tags: python, xslt, xpath, python-2.7

The following is the sample xml:

```
 <root>
    <slide name="abc.xml" nav_info="foo" nav_lvl_1="foobar" nav_lvl_2="foobarz">
        <title>a</title>
        <Introduction>
            <para>b</para>
        </Introduction>
        <Text>
            <header>c</header>
            <para>d</para>
            <header>e</header>
            <para>f</para>
            <header>g</header>
            <para>h</para>
        </Text>
        <Statement>
            <para>i</para>
        </Statement>
    </slide>
</root>
```

I have to get the text of each node by using xslt... I do not have any issues getting the text of nodes `title` and `statement` but, when I try to loop through the node Text I get only teh first `header` and `para`. For better understanding here is what I am doing!

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@nav_info='foo'">
        <xsl:for-each select="Text">
            <xsl:if test="header">
                   <xsl:value-of select="header">
            </xsl:if
            <xsl:if test="para">
                    <xsl:value-of select="para">
            </xsl:if
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Thsi give sme output as:

`c` and `d`
Expected output...

```
c d e f g h
```

in order..Any suggestions please!
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using XSLT 1.0 your `<xsl:value-of select="header"/>` is returning only the value of the first.

You likely need only do the following, walking through all the children of `<Text>`:

```
<xsl:when test="@nav_info='foo'">
    <xsl:for-each select="Text/*">
       <xsl:value-of select=".">
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
```

There is no need to check for the individual elements.

If there is a risk of elements other than those named `<header>` and `<para>`, then use:

```
<xsl:when test="@nav_info='foo'">
    <xsl:for-each select="Text/header | Text/para">
       <xsl:value-of select=".">
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
```

The union construct `|` will ensure your nodes are processed in document order.

Comment: Thank you Mr Holman..I agree with the above...I have an extended question..As u mentioned, I need to go through the children but, I have to sort out the output i.e in the real implementation of my code I have to write the value of header and para onto different nodes during transformation. I have to check for one condition at a time.. like if it is `Text/header` do something or if it is `Text/para` do something..How do i implement this in xslt??

Comment: Then you wouldn't use `<xsl:value-of/>`, rather you can replace the `<xsl:for-each>` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="Text/*"/>` and have `<xsl:template match="header">` and `<xsl:template match="para">` in order to handle the presence of each and build the nodes you need in the output.